# How to check if files exists in FTP?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I want to check if the list of files  I have in a directory exists in another directory while making an FTP.

I have 4 files in a directory where I will be making the ftp, I need to check if those 4 files exists in the directory while in an FTP.

I have used the code below but I encountered an invalid command error.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOCALPATH="/var/opt/list"
DATE=`date '+'%Y%m%d%H''`
HOST="10.123.456.18"
USER="admin"
PSWD="admin"
DIR="/var/opt/check"
DIR2="/var/opt/final"
FILE=SME*

ftp -in $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PSWD
cd $DIR

if [[ $FILE -eq 1 ]] 
        then
            rm $FILE
        else 
            echo "The File SME.txt do not Exist";
fi

quit
exit;
EOF
```

I have 4 files in the $LOCALPATH that all starts with SME*, I want to check if those 4 files exists in $DIR. if they exist, I want to remove them in that directory and put them in $DIR2, if they do not exist, I want to put them in $DIR2. I did not get any chance to draw the mput code for $DIR2 since I am encountering the Invalid command error.

Please help. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: tried that also but still getting an invalid command error.

Comment: Then we need [mcve].